# Getting all the rows between first timestamp and the difference between first and second - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a requirement to get all the records between the times of two sign-ins of the user.

When we retrieve the row of the first sign in and get the first timestamp (t1), we want to get all the hits made by the user between this and the second timestamp (t2).

What I am doing is: getting the first timestamp (t1) and subtracting it with the second timestamp (t2) of the user. I'll then add the difference (t2-t1) with the first timestamp and run query to get all the hits between t1 and (t1+d).

### Hence there are two things I am trying to do: (Getting second timestamp and the difference)

`first timestamp (t1) is: 1507559316`

```
            SELECT
              id, timestamp, (timestamp - 1507559316) as Difference
            FROM
              login_activity l 
            WHERE 
                l.uid=445 AND timestamp > 1507559316
            ORDER BY
                timestamp
                LIMIT 1
```

### Getting all the rows between first timestamp and the Difference

`t1 = 1507559316
 difference = 1226`

```
          SELECT
              name, address, time
            FROM
              records r 
            WHERE 
                time BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(1507559316) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(1507559316 + 1226)
            ORDER BY
                time
```

Do you think it's the right way to approach this?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I would want to see how you are getting "first" and "second" timestamps (*in addition to sample data and expected result*). It seems you have assumed you are doing that efficiently, but that may not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I seriously have misunderstood something, your method is unnecessarily complicated. You seem to have `A` and `B` and then are re-computing `B` by doing `A + (B - A)`. This is mysterious.

Assuming that your first timestamp is in `t1`, you could simplify the first query to

```
SELECT
  id, timestamp AS t2
FROM
  login_activity l 
WHERE 
  l.uid=445 AND t2 > t1
ORDER BY
  timestamp
LIMIT 1
```

and your second query to

```
SELECT
  name, address, time
FROM
  records r 
WHERE 
  time BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(t1) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(t2)
ORDER BY
  time
```

There is no need to re-compute `t2` as `t1 + (t2 - t1)` and thus no need to compute the difference in the first place.